# How can I lock a specific column, but have part of the column modifiable by a user? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So I am creating a worksheet to allow the user to enter data by using a button to create a new line in the table.  I only want specific cells in the table and column to be modifiable.

I have used a similar function to the one below before, however now it is not working.

In this case I want the range from B7 to the end of the table to be modifiable by the user and the rest of the column to be locked.

```
Function ProtectionOn()

Sequencer.Select
Cells.Locked = True
Range("B7", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="test"

End Function
```

The easiest way I have found this to work is to use xlup from the end of the spreadsheet.  Any help to fix my function would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: please tell us the data range of your table

Comment: The range will constantly be updated with users adding new lines to the table as they add data.  Currently its B7:B12 but this will continuously increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead Function, use sub.

```
Sub ProtectionOn()

Sequencer.Select
Cells.Locked = True
Range("B7", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="test"

End Sub
```

If you need sub precedure, try like this.

Main procedure.

```
Sub test()
    ProtectionOn Sheets("Sequencer")
End Sub

Sub ProtectionOn(Ws As Worksheet)
    With Ws
        .Unprotect Password:="test" '<~~ add code
        .Cells.Locked = True
        .Range("B7", .Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Locked = False
        .Protect Password:="test"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I want to be able to call this function from my sub that creates a new line in my table.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can call one sub from another sub. `Function` is used to accept a return value from the call. Like y= **sum** (a,b).

Comment: Thanks @Dy.Lee and bulbus, this makes more sense! However I am still getting an error when using .Range("B7", ... and so on.  The error tells me "Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class".  Any ideas?

Comment: In ProtectionOn(Ws As Worksheet) code, after the line With Ws, add one line-   .Unprotect Password:="test", that will resolve your issue as it seems the sheet is protected while you are calling that procedure.

Comment: @sktneer I have a function earlier in my code names ProtectionOff which unprotects my sheet.  I tried adding your suggestion too but still received the same error.

Comment: @LJohnstone,  I missed  .Unprotect Password:="test",

Comment: When the code produces an error, stop the code and go to the Review Tab and check the protection status of the sheet.

Comment: @sktneer the review tab is still asking for the sheet to be protected

Comment: Does the range .Range("B7", .Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)) contain any merged cells in it? If yes, that may also be the cause behind that error.

Comment: @sktneer yes it does! I never even thought about that.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Bottom rule is never have merged cells. They are going to be a headache for you later or sooner. Just get rid of them if possible and if you are at the early stage of your project. Otherwise, have some code to unmerge them before setting the lock property and merge them again after that. That's the only possible way around. :)

Comment: @sktneer Thank you so much for your help! I'm still pretty early in the project but I may struggle to avoid merging cells as it needs to be as simple as possible for the user.  I'll have a think about this and see if there is a way.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! That's great. Yes, there must be a way to get rid out of them, just spend some time with it. :)

Comment: As a side note, there is an alignment setting also which looks similar to the merged cells. To test it, on a blank sheet, write something in cell A1 --> Select A1:E1 --> Ctrl+1 to open cell format window --> on Alignment Tab --> in the Horizontal drop down, select Center Across Selection --> click on OK to finish. Now the text which you entered in A1 will look like if the cells A1:E1 are merged but they are not. See if you can use it for your purpose.

Comment: A little reformatting and I was able to make it work! That's a great tip for making cells look like they are merged! Thanks for all your help @sktneer

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that we have the table1 in sheet Sequencer please Create:

```
Sub ProtectionOn(sh As Worksheet)

Dim i As Long

With sh

i = .Range("Table1[#All]").Rows.Count

.Cells.Locked = True
.Range("b7", .Range("Table1[#All]").End(xlDown)).Locked = False
.Protect Password:="test"

End With

End Sub




  'and call it from:


Sub call_protect()

    ProtectionOn Sheets("Sequencer")



End Sub
```